# Unable to access Watson Assistant via Python API - Error: Resource not found, Code: 404

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to download the workspace from Watson assistant using python.

```
assistant = assistant = AssistantV1(
    version='2019-02-28',
    iam_apikey='',
    url='https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'
)
language = 'en'
workspace_id = "" #Skill Name:Poor mans disambiguation
#Frankfurt: https://api.eu-de.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com

response=assistant.list_workspaces().get_result()
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

list.wokpace is working fine - below sample output

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    {
      "name": "1 - DEV ENGLISH",
      "language": "en",
      "metadata": {
        "api_version": {
          "major_version": "v1",
          "minor_version": "2019-02-28"
        }
```

But while I am trying to export the workspace using 
`response = assistant.get_workspace(workspace_id=workspace_id, export=True)`

```
ApiException: Error: Resource not found, Code: 404 , X-global-transaction-id: a5e6e2ff76d987798c7c844b232f7f18
```

Note - I working on working on the workspace deployment automation.

Hope I get some help here.

Comment: Take a look at my Python tool which allows to download the workspace (and test dialogs, etc): https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script to download the workspace JSON Assitant

```
Api_key = ''
Skill_id = ''
Service_url = ''

start = time.time()
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(Api_key)
assistant = AssistantV1(version='2019-02-28',authenticator = authenticator)
assistant.set_service_url(Service_url)
response=assistant.get_workspace(workspace_id=Skill_id).get_result()
end = time.time()
print("Execution time : ",end - start)

response = assistant.get_workspace(
    workspace_id=Skill_id, export=True).get_result()
```

Answer (score 1):

Either it is a temporary error or you are not passing in the correct workspace ID. The [get_workspace() API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=python#get-information-about-a-workspace) which is part of the V1 API requires the workspace ID, not the skill ID.

I have [Python tools based on V1 and V2](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool) and here is the [call to that get_workspace](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/blob/master/wctool.py#L80):

```
# Get and print a specific workspace by ID
def getPrintWorkspace(workspaceID,exportWS):
    print(json.dumps(assistant.get_workspace(workspace_id=workspaceID,export=exportWS).get_result(), indent=2))
```

It is similar to what is documented and to your call, so everything should be fine with your code. Check the parameter value.